# MHT file Printing takes time

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-11, webbrowser-control

I am using C# application with  **WebBrowser control** to render and print MHT file using Internet explorer(IE).

recent i faced more time issue while print MHT file, single file took around a 1 hour to print file.
investigating MHT file, i found this file having more **Links** which may require to connect with internet and takes time load details.

This same files works fine with the older IE version having the "**Work Offline**" option. In current IE11 version work offline option is removed.

So any one have any idea how to resolve this time consumption issue of MHT file while print.

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove some links from the file and check whether it will decrease the print time? Besides, can you tell use your environments (include the OS version, .net framework and WebBrowser control version and the IE browser version) or post enough code reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: Yes removing some link Reduce the print time but it also lost some reference Images to Print, so that solution not accepted by our testing team, we use Window10, IE11 version and .NET framework 4.7.2 and latest webbrowser control

Comment: Please check your code and try to enable cache to store page resource, such as images.